# Independence of random vectors implies independence

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose we have some sequence of random variables $X_t$ with $t\in\mathbb{Z}$. Now suppose that we have that the vectors $(\ldots,X_{t-1},X_t)$ and $(X_{t+1},X_{t+2},\ldots)$ are independent for all $t$. How can I prove that the sequence $X_t$ is actually itself independent? Thanks for any hints or help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $Y=(Y_1,\ldots,y_m)$ and $Z=(Z_1,\ldots,Z_n)$ are independent vectors and $g,h$ measurable functions, then also $g(Y)$ and $h(Z)$ are independent. Choosing $$g(y_1,\ldots,y_m) := y_j \qquad \text{and} \qquad h(z_1,\ldots,z_n) := z_k,$$ we find that $Y_j$ and $Z_k$ are independent for any $j \in \{1,\ldots,m\}$ and $k \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$.

Now, since by assumption $(\ldots,X_{t-1},X_t)$ and $(X_{t+1},X_{t+2},\ldots)$ are independent, we get that $X_t$ and $X_s$, $s \geq t+1$, are independent. Similarly, the independence of $(\ldots,X_{t-2},X_{t-1})$ and $(X_t,X_{t+1},\ldots)$ implies the independence of $X_t$ and $X_s$ for any $s \leq t-1$. This shows that $X_s$ and $X_t$ are independent.

Using an induction one can show that $X_{t_1},\ldots,X_{t_n}$ are independent for any $t_1,\ldots,t_n \in \mathbb{Z}$.